# How to make sure if I rescued all the data from a corrupted ext4 partition?

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, disk-image, sata

Here's the history log of the partition:

- https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-d306970d9822474714fbfa85aab4af94
- sorted with unique entries: https://cloudvyzor.com/logpad/?query&database=sandbox-973a1d4d32264b1768ec9c9256a71424

On a recent post about this topic they concluded that it was a problem on the sata controller.

The partition has a bad superblock and lots of i-node errors, I made several backups of the faulty partition, first at the whole disk, the whole partition, and many image files of the partitions.

At whole drive clone it recognizes the ext4 filesystem, which isn't recognized on the faulty drive, but all other errors persist.

Instead the image files are found to be totally clean without errors and mounts smoothly as loop device, this is how I recovered around 300 GB of files that I think it's all what it was in that drive, but I'm not super sure.

Btw answering yes to all the i-node errors detected by fsck results on half of the files wiped out, I know this because I tested it on a cloned disk.

1. Can you explain all this magic?
2. How can I make sure that efectively I rescued all the data?

Comment: You rescued all the data your tools could find. See `http://www.porcupine.org/forensics/tct.html` for otjer tools. If an `inode` is faulty, the data blocks it points to are lost. `inodes` have pointers to everything on the filesystem.

Comment: but why cloning the partition to an image and mounting the image as read only loop apparently solved the problem? even fsck couldn't find errors on the partition image.